# SELECT Query - Can you add data into the second record only?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I have a question for all of the SQL wizards out there and that is can I add data into the second record in a SELECT query only?

I thought I'd ask here first to see if this is even possible? At the moment the first row is filled with mandatory data that needs to stay there (FileVersion and FileName). What I need from the second row is for "2A" to appear in record 2 only, but as you see it's also appearing in 3 & 4.

[image: Example]

[image: Example2]

I've been experimenting with TOP but had little success. I am using T-SQL. If you need any additional info then please just ask :-D.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I was thinking perhaps a CASE statement using ROW_NUMBER or ID?

Comment: What is the query?  The rows returned from a SQL query have no ordering, unless you have an `order by` in the query.  So you also need to specify what the ordering is.

Comment: There is no ordering in the query. Do you reckon if I order by say.. a unique identifier I could then use ROW_NUMBER to insert "2A" in the right place

Comment: . . The answer to your question is "yes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such logic as second row. This may change from time to time, so you need some kind of column(s) to determine what defines second row. I used ID in my example.

```
declare @t table(id int, col1 varchar(20), col2 varchar(20))

insert @t values(1, 'a', 'a')
insert @t values(2, 'b', 'b')
insert @t values(3, 'c', 'c')

SELECT id, 
case when row_number() over (order by id)= 2 then '2A' else col1 end col1, col2 
FROM @t
```

Comment: All sorted.. I had quite a bit more work to do on it but it finally works as I wanted it to.